# Is there a reason why certain sites don't allow periods in passwords?

Tags: database, security

I was just wondering why certain website don't allow anything other than letter and numbers in the password field.

Is there a security reason or perhaps it's just a limitation of the DB they are using? Thanks for the info.

Edit: It appears that Oracle's database doesn't acknowledge uppercase and lowercase? Is this true? I was told that via PM. Thanks for the information guys, this is really useful stuff.

I wonder why this question has 3 votes to close though. Not enough jQuery and freehand circles?

Comment: I tend to not trust sites that have such a requirement.  "How are you storing my password that such a requirement would even matter?" is a common reaction.

Comment: @David: I agree, in the applications I've made there has never been a problem when storing any character I wanted. I wonder if there is a reason though, I only program with C#, so I might not now about other language restrictions.

Comment: ...and why can't you write code so that it doesn't matter.  It is fun using angle brackets '`<>`' in passwords.  And I have a distressing number of passwords which echo thoughts along the lines of "Waddya mean I cannot use punctuation in my password for your pathetic site?".

Comment: I wanted to ask the same question about accents in the username (most of the time I can not use GôTô as my username)

Comment: This would be better asked on SuperUser... but the Close -> Migrate option is gone...

Comment: @Jonathan: Yeah, that's always frustrating. I remember one time I tried to use a ten-character password, and the site told me my password was too long.

Comment: @Frus: Superuser is more an end user website, not a programming one. Since this question is asking specifically about programming reasons behind this choice, it belongs here.

Comment: @Sergio: The way it's currently written, it's not immediately obvious that it's a programming question. I know non-programmers (but with other IT experience) ask similar questions.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: Migrate has been merged with Off-Topic as part of the effort to add new SE sites as options.  The idea is that something is "off topic" either in general (default) or because it should be moved to another site.

Comment: I don't know how else to word it, I think the meaning and purpose of the question is clear enough.

Comment: @Sergio: I would have phrased it more explicitly as "Is there a programmatic reason to not allow period-characters in passwords?"

Comment: @David: I found it a useful feature, but you have a point. Is it being replaced with a generic "Migrate to..." where users can fill in the URL for a different SE site?  Sort of like how when you close something as duplicate you can specify which you think the duplicate is.

Comment: @GôTô - that's likely to do with character sets and the like. It'd be possible, for example, to create two usernames that look the exact same if you'd allow UTF-8 characters in a username, which could lead to identity fraud and/or impersonification of important users such as administrators. There's not much reason to not allow all of the latin character set characters though, such as áccéñts above usernames - unless the writer of the software doesn't know how to handle different character sets.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: (I'm sure there's more discussion of this on Meta, and on the blog.) I don't think they're going to add free input like that, more likely they'll add related sites as they leave beta and get promoted to full SE sites.  That whole thing is still pretty new.

Comment: Wouldn't this be more on topic on webmasters.stackexchange.com?  SU has been defined so it's explicitly not about web stuff.

Comment: Not really, this is programming related and not really meant as a question for an end user or a webmater to answer. I wanted specific programming reasons.

Comment: There are too many options for where to go - it is too hard to work out whether a question belongs.  It was bad enough with the Trilogy; it is progressively getting harder and harder.

Comment: How is this off-topic? As I understand the question, he's not asking how this relates to personal preferences of the site owner, but whether there is some PROGRAMMING reason for doing this.

Comment: I know a site that requires first eight characters to be unique, start with an alphabet and contain only alphabets and numbers. I suspect they do a code generation from the password to create an identifier :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No reason at all, except for sloppy DB coding where they would allow plain text in the DB or use the (non-portable) DB functions to hash the password and use direct SQL statement.
This seems just like plain string validation.

Other than that, on the practical side, special character placement in foreign or cramped keyboard is tricky and might be more frustrating for users that are traveling (or in the more modern case alternative input like onscreen keyboard on smartphone).
Some websites might even push the system further by providing their own on-screen keyboard to log in (with various scrambling).

Disallowing special characters helps QA, and reduces multi-platform user frustration.

And finally, allowing a limited (deemed safe) character set (that is not only punctuation but also more language specific characters in Unicode), developer can also avoid encoding confusion between the browser and the server application (form data encoding is not very clear in the standard, and can be tricky on some browsers).

Comment: Allowing special characters doesn't have to mean Requiring special characters. If the user knows that they will be logging in on a system that makes it hard to type these characters, the sensible solution is to not use those characters.

Comment: In an ideal worlrd the user would know of course, but in some very general cases (95% of the case), would that be because the mobile site is added after, or the user didn't know about foreign keyboard layout before they travel for example.

Comment: Disallowing certain characters because *some* users *might* travel to sites that *might* not make typing them easy — and those users *might* not know how to work around that — would be strange.

Comment: Might induce some frustration, and the target of the website is not known, plus I mentioned the possibility of having a mobile website with more limited/frustrating input, or worst (videogame system).

Comment: I have never not been able to find the period on any keyboard.

Comment: humm, so you a telling me your password contains a period ;) , I already experienced different keyboard from different country, and for example I havea japanese version of a fujitsu u2010 where the back quote would be a combination like this "shift+fn+." http://pocketables.typepad.com/photos/uncategorized/2008/11/25/fujitsu_looxu_comp_kb.jpg (even worse usually the backslash is the yen symbol), even french keyboard got e accent cute which french wouldn't consider as much as special.

Comment: and french mac keyboard doesnt show braces/brackets http://www.whytraveltofrance.com/images/azertykeyboard.jpg

Answer (score 22):

They're brain-dead and scared of punctuation in general - and dot counts as punctuation.  It is more a case of 'friendly-fire' than dot being dangerous.  Dash is pretty harmless too.

One of the concerns is [SQL Injection](http://xkcd.com/327), of course.  The other is competency of programming workforce.

Comment: In previous jobs where our own systems had requirements like this (for example, I once worked at a bank that allowed ONLY letters and numbers in users' passwords), it was often a matter of "that's what the 3rd party system/widget/solution we bought requires."  So sometimes the "competency" issue goes back to whoever decided to buy it (usually not programmers) and whoever they bought it from.

Comment: Chase is one of those companies. It boggles the mind how a site like Stack Overflow allows me to configure a more secure password than my *banking* site. *sigh*

Comment: If punctuation in the password becomes an SQL injection concern, **they're doing it wrong.**

Answer (score 11):

I worked at one place that wanted to be able to read passwords over the phone (that's how support was done).  Support people didn't know all the names for symbols (hash, bang, pipe, ampersand/and, asterisk/star) and other issues (which left bracket do you mean, which quote, etc).  So they didn't allow any punctuation.

Not a good reason (support shouldn't know my password), but you didn't ask for only good reasons :)

Comment: This is a good reason, and a valid one to eliminate some symbols.  Not just anyone in support should have your password, but when someone can access your billing details (CC number, billing address), modify your account, or has physical access to your machine (or a machine hosting your content/services), you've already trusted them with far more than what your account password protects.  That said, most sites  never need to do this, because interacting over the phone or in person is an extreme rarity.

Comment: (Should I mention you should never use the same password in multiple places?)

Comment: @Roger Pate: I use a good system where the center body of the password is the same, but the extremities are different according to the website. Works very well and doubt anybody would notice a pattern right away.

Comment: @Sergio: That's common, but unless you know details about how the password is managed and stored for every site (and you don't), you can't trust it to protect other passwords.  I'd not use it unless the conversion is clearly one-way, but usually that eliminates the benefit for most people of figuring out the password in their head.  Instead, I use unique passwords and manage them in KeePass[X].

Answer (score 4):

There is *no* possible reason. They are just incompetent. Any concerns about SQL injection or anything else is just wrong. That just tells you that they are worried about a possible security injection because they aren't hashing or encrypting your password.

Comment: There is other concerns than technical. See user479383 comment for an example. In general, you are making a general statement which needs proof, not just examples for cases that one might come up with.

Answer (score 1):

About upper/lower case: if you store the password in plain text, then that might be an issue. I'm not sure about Oracle, but SqlServer considers 'Password' and 'passWORD' to be identical.

If you store the password as hash, then the casing of the original is not a problem: the password acts case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

OWASP is pretty clear on the subject. Its first piece of guidance in the [OWASP Passwood Storage Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) is:

**Do not limit the character set and set long max lengths for credentials**
Some organizations restrict the 1) types of special characters and 2) length of credentials accepted by systems because of their inability to prevent SQL Injection, Cross-site scripting, command-injection and other forms of injection attacks. These restrictions, while well-intentioned, facilitate certain simple attacks such as brute force.

Do not allow short or no-length passwords and do not apply character set, or encoding restrictions on the entry or storage of credentials. Continue applying encoding, escaping, masking, outright omission, and other best practices to eliminate injection risks.

A reasonable long password length is 160. Very long password policies can lead to DOS in certain circumstances[1](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet).

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it to avoid all possible [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)?

Comment: @Goto, how would `.` be in danger of allowing SQL injection? `--` , `;`, `'`, and SQL keywords would be more dangerous.

Comment: I doubt it';DROP TABLE Users;--

Comment: @Goto: Why would a '.' enable SQL injection?

Comment: @Brad: I'm no expert and don't know how you could perform SQL injection other than by using a `'`, but I'm sure it is not the only way. Plus the question is about other characters than letter and numbers.

Comment: @GoTo, for some reason I thought the OP was about `.` only in the username.

Comment: They probably think it's safer that way, but restricting characters in the input field is not the right way to solve SQL injection.  See http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Possibly, but disallowing certain characters in usernames then is a sign that the developer is either lazy or doesn't know how to prevent such attacks properly.

Comment: @Cthulhu: indeed, and that's a pain, considering my username has two accents!